# get input values from "Instead of Insert" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having problem with instead of trigger in SQL Server. I want to check the value before insert. If the value exist, executed insert will aborted. Here is the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_fakultas
ON fakultas
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM fakultas WHERE fnama = NEW.fnama  )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Nama fakultas sudah ada.', 0, 0);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the INSERTED psuedo-table but why not use a Unique index to avoid using code?

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_fnama ON fakultas(fnama)
```

Otherwise, if you want to use code

```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fakultas WHERE fnama IN (SELECT fnama FROM INSERTED))
    ...
```

Both solutions deal with multiple rows from an INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your trigger.

1. the records about to be inserted to the table are stored in a tabled called inserted, so you need to replace `NEW.fnama` with `NEW.inserted`.
2. your trigger assumes only one row would be inserted every time. 
   However, this is not true. multiple rows might be inserted to the table.
3. This trigger is an Instead of insert trigger. as it is written, no records would ever be inserted to the table, since you need to write the insert statement inside the trigger itself if you want records to be inserted to the table.
4. raising an error inside an instead of trigger is usually bad practice.

I would suggest to drop that trigger and instead create a unique constraint on the `fnama` column. This will enable you to inserted only unique values to the table and will have better performance then an instead of trigger. Also, it will prevent updating a row and setting a value to that column that already exists in a different row.

```
ALTER TABLE fakultas 
  ADD CONSTRAINT UC_fnama UNIQUE (fnama);
```